# Gparted made an error on USB

Tags: windows-7, usb, kali-linux, gparted

I am Kali linux user and I want to install Windows 7.

I tried to make bootable USB flash drive in Kali and it failed due unknown reasons. Then I tried to do it with help of Android.

I bought an OTG cable and inserted USB to phone. I copied Windows 7 ISO to phone and tried to make bootable USB using ISO2USB(App on Google Play). I selected my USB drive and ISO file, then pressed to Start. It showed error as:

> “Requires Fat32 filesystem USB.”

I changed it to Fat32 using Gparted,then tried again. It loaded till 10% and after this showed error

> “Could not write to device, result == -1 errno 0 null”

I tried it several times and decided to format USB using Gparted. But when I wanted to format it, it showed USB drive different:

[image: error N1]

I tried create partition table but it showed error again:

[image: error N2]

Then I tried to format USB stick on Android too and it not worked too.

I already tried all methods and all failed. How I can turn my USB drive back to useful drive and after this how to make bootable Windows 7 USB flash drive from Kali linux 2019.4?

Comment: What exactly was the question? Also, please add more info about the linux "unknown reasons". What tools did you use? Did you tried to burn an iso image?

Comment: @GeoMint here is your answers:

Question:How I can format my USB drive even it shows "Read-Only" error?(I don't have another PC for formatting)

Reasons:After UNetBootIn ended process it show a message:"Restart your PC and choose Unetbotin in Bootloader.". I done everything as it said but faced with this error:
***File /boot/ubnkern not found. You need to load the kernel first.***(I chose Hard Drive before Unetbootin done process. 

And..... Yes I tried to burn iso image but not worked too.

Comment: So to understand. After doing all that your computer does not recognize the usb when you connect it to linux? Also can you comment a screenshot of your full gparted?

Comment: @GeoMint,It doesn't shows it at File Explorer of Kali linux,but shows at Gparted.
And.... Comments of Screenshots: I wanted to make a new partition and format USB drive again but couldn't due Gparted looked like this and showed error when I wanted to format it.(I couldn't understand why it shows like this.)

Comment: what info about USB drive is shown in gnome disk utility ? Attach a screenshot . Also  add outputs of : sudo gdisk /dev/sdx . Also as a note use woeusb https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB to create bootable windows usb from linux.

Comment: @RunningChild what info about USB drive is shown in gnome disk utility ? Attach a screenshot . Also  add outputs of : sudo gdisk /dev/sdx . Also as a note use woeusb https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB to create bootable windows usb from linux.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't find a solution with Gparted i suggest using fdisk.

Run as sudo:

```bsh
fdisk -l # Make sure your device address is correct
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc # format into Fat32 ( assuming /dev/sdc is the device you wish to format )
```

Comment: Not works :(
It shows  
`mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc: Read-only file system`

Comment: Try `umount /dev/sdc`

Comment: It shows `umount: /dev/sdc: not mounted.` (I guess it means that USB already unmounted.)

Comment: `You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here.`

Comment: No worries. Can you run `hdparm -r0 /dev/sdc` ? you might to install it first

Comment: Done,but still same:Gparted not changed,File Explorer same too.(And I am new here.So,excuse me for any mistakes =] )

Comment: now `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc`, it shouldn't say read-only anymore

Comment: But said ;D It shows `mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc: Read-only file system` again ;D

Comment: I'm out of ideas so i have two suggestions. 1- try mounting the iso again using Etcher this time. its my preference, if you don't like it use another iso burner to usb. 2- Find a pc with windows and it should recognize the usb, so format it there

Comment: Tried Etcher too and it not worked too.And I can't find Windows PC :|     But...... can Virtual Machine work or not?

Comment: In any case try unplug and plug again the usb to the computer and try again the commands.

Comment: Not works. But thanks for your attention. Arigato! =]

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I done it. I don't need Kali for now so,I used one trick(Do this trick if there is no other ways). I made a volume using gparted and used that volume as bootable device. Then I found a program: python3-multibootUSB.It helped me to make that volume as bootable device.Chose that volume and ISO file and Done!

Rebooted device.After reboot I saw Windows Rescue Mode at Grub. I chose that option and started setup of Win7. Then installed and done! I not tried to solve USB drive's problem yet but I guess Diskpart will work.

***Note:After installation you will not able to access the volume that you made for booting.***